# Is there API to access "new" My Maps in Google Maps Engine Lite

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-engine

I've been using "classic" My Maps because they had API go access all Maps and their data. But recently I have received an email telling me that all maps will be migrated soon to the new "Google Engine Lite" "My Maps". In fact, my apps have stop working because the previous APIs don't work anymore.

I've been looking for the equivalent API for the maps without any luck.

I have a test application that can use OAuth to access my "new" maps. But, when listing maps just those created with the new "Maps Engine" show up. Not any of the "My Maps" do.

It's critical for me to know if there is any equivalent API for the new "My Maps". Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for Google MyMaps (formerly Maps Engine Lite) at this time.  Vote up this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2953) if you want to see it happen.